# How to disable automatic SCM Trigger from jenkinsFile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees, build-triggers

i am new to jenkinspipeline. Do you have an example of how i can use jenkinsfile to prevent automatic scm trigger in jenkinsfile? I was hoping for something like properties[autoSCMTrigger: false].

I have tried for now by allowing the build to fail if a certain param is not checked manually and that works for now but it does not look nice if every commit triggers a fail build.

I know that you can set the the disable automatic SCM triggering under Configuration>build trigger but i cannot seem to save it as i am using jenkins project or some other version.

I want to know if there is a way to set it in JENKINSFILE. eg properties([autoSCMTrigger: false])